# jQuery jsonp ajax status never acquired

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have a function which puts some text in an table cell (identified "#FilesList") like following:

```
   $.fn.LogsListRefresh = function()
    {
        var Result;
        var prom = new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
        Result = $.ajax(
        { dataType: "jsonp" // needed because of "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" error
        , url : "http://" + $( "#IPAddress" ).val() + ":" + $( "#PortNumber" ).val()
        , data: { "Question" : "list" }
        , jsonpCallback: "$.fn.ServerCallback_FilesList"
        , succes: function( res ){ console.log( "Res=" + res + "=" ); } // never hit
        , error : function( res ){ console.log( "Res=" + res + "=" ); } // never hit
        })
        });
        prom.then(
            function()
            {
                console.log( "Success" ); // never hit
            },
            function()
            {
                console.log( "Error" ); // never hit
            }
        );
        console.log( "Result=" + Result.status + "=" );
        $( "#FilesList" ).html( "Communication Error! Check IP Address and Port Number." );
    }
```

This, generally, works fine, callback is called, I get the data I need etc., the only problems is that I can't get an execution status. I have tried with and without Promise. None of Success or Fail functions is ever hit no matter Ajax call was ok or not. What I'm interested mostly is an error feedback in case server can not be reached or something. The donkey style I'm doing this now, as shown, is to use that last statement which it seems is executed only in case of Ajax problems.

Comment: `succes` or `success`

Comment: @Ryuk Lee
Indeed, made a difference. :)

Comment: @Ryuk Lee I see now that error method is called even if result is 200, and success is never called

Comment: Did you fix the `succes` text?

Comment: @Ryuk Lee Yes I did.